# Using Zoho mail with Trigger Email from Firestore

Tags: firebase, email, triggers, zoho

I have my own domain, lets say it is mydomain.com and with that domain I have setup Zoho mail, because it is free up to five addresses. I am trying to create SMTP_CONNECTION_URI for this firebase extesion, but it always fails on smtp authentification.

When creting the URI I was inspired what Zoho has provided

https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/zoho-smtp.html#alink2

My URI looks like this:

smtps://noreply@mydomain.com:password@smtp.zoho.com:465

I have also tried using **smtppro.zoho.com** and with no success.

I have also tried smtp.

I have also tried port 587

I have also tried without password and provided password as ENV variable as stated by the extension

> Secure format: smtps://username@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465 (username only) smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465 (No username and password) Backwards Compatible (less secure): smtps://username@gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465. (username and password)

Different combinations listed above were tried, but with no success.

Here is the error message provided by extension:

[image]

I was expecting it to work, since I think I have followed all instructions provided by the documentation, but correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try generating [App Specific Password](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/two-factor-authentication.html#alink7)? So the url will be: `smtps://email@mydomain.com:appspecificpassword@smtppro.zoho.com:465`

Comment: Yes, app specific password does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, that I was testing it from emulator. When setting up an emulator it asks for a password, but it puts the password inside `firestore-send-email.secret.local` and the passowrd is not being used. Solution is to put the passowrd inside `firestore-send-email.env` to variable as this `SMTP_PASSWORD=mypass`